# Evaluate the line integrals

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, line-integrals

> Evaluate the line integrals $\int_C G(x,y) dx$, $\int_C G(x,y) dy$, and $\int_C G(x,y) ds$ on the indicated curve C.
>   $$G(x,y) = 3x^2 +6y^2; y=2x+1, -1 \le x \le 0$$

I feel like this problem should be really easy, but I'm having a lot of trouble figuring it out.  The answers at the back of my textbook are 3, 6, and $3\sqrt{5}$.  If anyone could show me how to do this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just an fyi, this is not complex analysis. Complex Analysis deals with calculus involving complex numbers instead of just real numbers.

Comment: I just stuck it in there because it comes from my complex analysis textbook and is for my complex analysis class.  I know that there are no complex numbers involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do the first one; hopefully this will give you some insight into how to attack the other two :)

Since the integral is with respect to $x$, it would be nice if we could parametrize $C$ with $x$. In fact this is the form in which it's given: $C = \{(x, 2x + 1) : -1 \leq x \leq 0\}$. Therefore:

$$\int_C G(x, y)dx \space = \int_{x = -1}^{x = 0} (3x^2 + 6(2x + 1)^2)dx \space = \space 3\int_{-1}^0 (9x^2 + 8x + 2)dx$$

You can finish it from there, and it does indeed equal 3. Hope this helps!

Comment: That does help but I'm still a little confused about how to approach the integral where C is parameterized with y.  I was thinking I could solve the equation y=2x+1 for x, and also solve to find what values of y I should integrate over (I got -1 to 1) and I wasn't getting the right answer. I also tried finding dy but that didn't work either...

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out.  Thanks for your help!